# Is there a way to install on a laptop when the BIOS version is older than 2000?

Tags: system-installation, bios

Is there a way to install Ubuntu on a laptop when the BIOS version is older than 2000? When I try to, the installation fails. I have tried early versions of Ubuntu as well.

When first booting, it reports that the BIOS is older than 2000, then boots to the installation menu and goes through pre-install setup. When the installation starts, it locks up. I think the laptop might be too old. It has a Pentium 2 processor with 512 MB of RAM at 333 Mhz.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my BIOS is older than that on one PC. Specifically what is failing?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If your question is about a laptop, could you please list your exact laptop brand and model number so we can better help you? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu server? I have a Compaq Armada M700 that I rarely use. It used to have Windows XP, then I tried Ubuntu in Wubi [a couple of years ago] which failed. In the past 6 months I netbooted the Ubuntu server installer and after following the prompts, the aging machine has Ubuntu server installed. Things are slow [eg SSHing from another machine takes 10-20 seconds for password prompt/shell load] but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a BIOS problem at ALL. It never is. I'm sorry, but your computer is horribly slow for Ubuntu... I found that out before seeing the minimum system requirements. A Pentium 2 @ 333 MHz with 512 MB of RAM compared to the minimum system requirements for Ubuntu is comparing a turtle to a car. Try installing Lubuntu instead. It is a version of Ubuntu with much less requirements and a lighter interface and according to their site on Ubuntu wiki, it can run on your system, although not fast enough for daily use...

In case you do not need a graphical user interface (GUI) and can use the command line (consult Google), you can use Ubuntu Server instead, which is super lightweight, but I wouldn't use it to do anything the average user does, since, sadly, it cannot do that stuff.

You can consider a $35 Raspberry Pi 2 if your computer is a desktop, and that microcomputer can run Ubuntu and is a sports car to the computer you have.